# How to test on multi phones using uiautomator ？

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have create test case for Android, which including scenarios like this:
    1) Active the phone 
    2) Compose message and send out to another number

Here the problem is:

For the send-receive test case, I have not find a way to verify from receiving side. Because using  getUiDevice() in UiAutomatorTestCase, it only returns current device instance.
How can I get the other device?

Comment: you may have to make code for two separate jar files for sending and receiving. And run separately.

Answer (score 0):

As Uiautomator test cases are run in the device being tested, you cannot get hold of another device from the device under test. Therefore it is not possible to test your scenario with UIautomator. 
You can look in to MonkeyRunner for testing this kind of scenarios. MonkeyRunner test cases run on your PC, therefore you can write test scenarios involving multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UiMutilator](https://github.com/vidstige/UiMutilator/releases) library to accomplish this. It exposes an interface very similar to the UiAutomator which makes it very easy to convert any existing test. It was made for testing messaging application and such. You can interleave commands on different devices like so

```
UiDevice first = getUiDevice().first();
UiDevice second = getUiDevice().second();
first.pressHome();
second.pressHome();
```

As a bonus you are not limited to jUnit, but can use TestNG or such.

It uses UiAutomator on the various devices behind the scenes.